# Using tablekit for Sorting a table that is returned from an AJAX method

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, tablesorter

I am returning a set of results from an ajax call like so

```
<g:submitToRemote update="updateMe" action="getParams" asynchronus="false" value="Search" name="SearchButton" type="hidden"/>
```

This is putting the results of that call at the updateMe DIV tag.

Now, I am actually rendering a table from my controller like this:

```
render(view: 'ajaxResults', model:[results:resultRows])
```

where ajaxResults is a template that looks like:

```
        <div class="list">
            <h1>Query Results</h1>
            <table style="width: 80%; align: center;" class="sortable resizable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>                      
                        <th id="emp_name" class="sortfirstasc">Employee Name</th>
                        <th id="title">Title</th>
                        <th id="labor_grade">Labor Grade</th>
                        <th id="name">Hit</th>
                        <th id="total_exp">Experience (Yrs)</th>                      
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <g:each in="${results}" status="i" var="search">
                        <tr>                      
                            <td><g:link controller="employee" action="edit" id="${search.id}">${search.emp_name?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></td>                              
                            <td>${search.title?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
                            <td>${search.labor_grade?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
                            <td>${search.name?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
                            <td>${search.total_exp?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>                                                                                 
                        </tr>
                    </g:each>
                </tbody>


            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="paginateButtons">
            <g:paginate total="${Search.count()}" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is - this table is not actually sortable. I am trying to use the tablekit

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/tablekit.css" />        
<g:javascript library="tablekit"></g:javascript>
```

I think the problem is that I am inserting this and it is not re-rendering to give me the sorted table. How can I force this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the tablekit performs an action on page load that locates the decorated elements and applies JavaScripts methods.

Use the `after` parameter or `onComplete` event on `submitToRemote` tag to call a JavaScript function to re-apply the sorting behaviour.

Something along the lines of:

```
<g:submitToRemote ... after="reapplySortable">
```

and in js

```
<script>
  function reapplySortable() {
    TableKit.Sortable.init(table, {options});  
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I too searched for this on google and everywhere else but found nothing ... 
but it was funny when I found the answer in the FAQs of tablekit website after extensive search elsewhere!!
There are only two FAQs and the second one is the one which is searched for by most people, like me.
[visit](http://www.millstream.com.au/view/code/tablekit/) for full details.
It says:

```
TableKit.reloadTable(tablename);
```

to force TableKit to reinitialise.

Hope this helps.